Trying to unmarshal two patterns using XStream's conversion class, but it's not working
Pattern 1
<value>Hello</value>

Pattern 2
<value>
  <expression>
    map.message
  </expression>
</value>

Model
@XStreamAlias("value")
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = "text")
class ValueNode {

  private String text;

  private ExpressionNode node;
　
　// setter / getter
}
@XStreamAlias("expression")
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = "text")
class ExpressionNode {

  private String text;

　// setter / getter
}

Actual data after unmarshalling




ValueNode.text
ValueNode.node
ExpressionNode.text




Pattern 1
"Hello"
null
-


Pattern 2
"\n\t\n"
null
-



Expected data after unmarshalling




ValueNode.text
ValueNode.node
ExpressionNode.text




Pattern 1
"Hello"
null
-


Pattern 2
null
Instance
"map.message"




@XStreamImplicit implies a collection does it not? How many expressions have you got?

Also, to unmarshal correctly into that bean, your xml should be <value><expression><text>map.message</text></expression></value>

@g00se XStreamImplicit  I wrote it wrong, so I deleted it. The xml side cannot be edited and must be unmarshalled with this content.
